# PHP - Adding element dynamically to each json object in array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using PHP for adding the JSON element to array.

This is my database table:

[image]

Here is my json array:

```
array:8 [

  0 => {#305
    +"Queue": "755"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
  }
  1 => {#306
    +"Queue": "752"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
  }
  2 => {#304
    +"Queue": "750"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
  }
]
```

Now I want to add **callQueueName** to every json object. Tried using put function as shown in below code but not getting added.

Here is my working code:

```
public static function getLoginAgentInfoTest(){
    $loginAgentInfo = 
      '[{"Queue":"755","Location":"427","MemberName":"PJSIP\/427","Status":"5"},
        {"Queue":"752","Location":"427","MemberName":"PJSIP\/427","Status":"5"},
        {"Queue":"750","Location":"427","MemberName":"PJSIP\/427","Status":"5"}]';

    $loginAgentInfo = json_decode($loginAgentInfo);
    
    $i = 0;
      
    foreach($loginAgentInfo[$i] as $loginData){ 
        
        $callQueueName = Tbcdrqueues::where('callqueue_no',$loginAgentInfo[$i]->Queue)->value('callqueue_name');
 
        $loginAgentInfo[$i].put('callQueueName',$callQueueName);
    
        $i++;
    }

    return $loginAgentInfo;
}
```

Expected output is:

```
array:8 [

  0 => {#305
    +"Queue": "755"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
    +"callQueueName" : "New claims"
  }
  1 => {#306
    +"Queue": "752"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
    +"callQueueName" : "Billing"
  }
  2 => {#304
    +"Queue": "750"
    +"Location": "427"
    +"MemberName": "PJSIP/427"
    +"Status": "5"
    +"callQueueName" : "Customer_Service"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Looks like you have just a plain array here, so what exactly is `$loginAgentInfo[$i].put(…)` supposed to be?

Comment: Btw., that is one of the weirdest ways to loop over an array with `foreach`, that I have ever seen.

Comment: Yeah, your problem are in the `put(...)` part, you should try with: 

$loginAgentInfo[$i]['callQueueName'] = $callQueueName; //or look at array_push() function

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($loginAgentInfo as $key => $loginData){ 
     $callQueueName = Tbcdrqueues::where('callqueue_no',$loginData->Queue)->value('callqueue_name');
     $loginAgentInfo[$key]->callQueueName = $callQueueName;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain the actual change and why it would work.